# CSS transition acting weird

Tags: css, transition

I have page with a SVG in it and I want to use transition to change the color slow when hovering over the image. But I can't get it to work. Can anyone please see what I'm doing wrong?

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/67vG4/1/

Html:

```
<svg height="67px" id="insta" style="enable-background:new 0 0 67 67;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 67 67" width="67px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path id="path" d="M42.271,26.578v-0.006c0.502,0,1.005,0.01,1.508-0.002  c0.646-0.016,1.172-0.57,1.172-1.217c0-0.963,0-1.927,0-2.89c0-0.691-0.547-1.24-1.236-1.241c-0.961,0-1.922-0.001-2.883,0  c-0.688,0.001-1.236,0.552-1.236,1.243c-0.001,0.955-0.004,1.91,0.003,2.865c0.001,0.143,0.028,0.291,0.073,0.426  c0.173,0.508,0.639,0.82,1.209,0.823C41.344,26.579,41.808,26.578,42.271,26.578z M33,27.817c-3.384-0.002-6.135,2.721-6.182,6.089  c-0.049,3.46,2.72,6.201,6.04,6.272c3.454,0.074,6.248-2.686,6.321-6.043C39.254,30.675,36.462,27.815,33,27.817z M21.046,31.116  v0.082c0,4.515-0.001,9.03,0,13.545c0,0.649,0.562,1.208,1.212,1.208c7.16,0.001,14.319,0.001,21.479,0  c0.656,0,1.215-0.557,1.215-1.212c0.001-4.509,0-9.02,0-13.528v-0.094h-2.912c0.411,1.314,0.537,2.651,0.376,4.014  c-0.161,1.363-0.601,2.631-1.316,3.803s-1.644,2.145-2.779,2.918c-2.944,2.006-6.821,2.182-9.946,0.428  c-1.579-0.885-2.819-2.12-3.685-3.713c-1.289-2.373-1.495-4.865-0.739-7.451C22.983,31.116,22.021,31.116,21.046,31.116z   M45.205,49.255c0.159-0.026,0.318-0.049,0.475-0.083c1.246-0.265,2.264-1.304,2.508-2.557c0.025-0.137,0.045-0.273,0.067-0.409  V21.794c-0.021-0.133-0.04-0.268-0.065-0.401c-0.268-1.367-1.396-2.428-2.78-2.618c-0.058-0.007-0.113-0.02-0.17-0.03H20.761  c-0.147,0.027-0.296,0.047-0.441,0.08c-1.352,0.308-2.352,1.396-2.545,2.766c-0.008,0.057-0.02,0.114-0.029,0.171V46.24  c0.028,0.154,0.05,0.311,0.085,0.465c0.299,1.322,1.427,2.347,2.77,2.52c0.064,0.008,0.13,0.021,0.195,0.03H45.205z M33,64  C16.432,64,3,50.568,3,34C3,17.431,16.432,4,33,4s30,13.431,30,30C63,50.568,49.568,64,33,64z" />
                    </svg>
```

Css:

```
#insta {
   display: block;
   float: right; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: -12px;
    -webkit-transition: fill 2s;  
    -moz-transition: fill 2s;  
    -o-transition: fill 2s;  
    transition: fill 2s;  
}
#insta:hover {
    fill: #ff0000;
}
```

Ok, I've tried a couple of different things and the only thing that seems to work for me (except changing browser) is when I remove everything but the svg from my body section. Does that mean that I have coded anything wrong you think?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem in Chrome or Firefox. I see your SVG slowly turning red on hover, then slowly turning back to its original when unhovered.

Comment: I just discovered the same thing when I tried different browsers. It must be a Safari thing then. Anyone?

Comment: It works just fine for me in Safari (v7.0.3) on Mac

Comment: It seems to be working fine in chrome

Comment: have you tried to refresh your page with ctrl f5, the browser maybe cached the image aggressively...

Comment: It seems to work when I remove the a-tag around the svg. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax isn't right for the `transition`.

Try:

```
-webkit-transition: fill 2s ease-out; 
transition: fill 2s ease-out;
```

Also if you set the `transition` on `#insta:hover` it will transition back.

```
#insta:hover {
    fill: #ff0000;
    -webkit-transition: fill 2s ease-out; 
    transition: fill 2s ease-out; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried it, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine for me (Using Chrome 34), just edited the CSS to show the full image.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>


<svg id="insta"  style="enable-background:new 0 0 67 67;" width="100" height="100">
<path id="path" d="M42.271,26.578v-0.006c0.502,0,1.005,0.01,1.508-0.002  c0.646-0.016,1.172-0.57,1.172-1.217c0-0.963,0-1.927,0-2.89c0-0.691-0.547-1.24-1.236-1.241c-0.961,0-1.922-0.001-2.883,0  c-0.688,0.001-1.236,0.552-1.236,1.243c-0.001,0.955-0.004,1.91,0.003,2.865c0.001,0.143,0.028,0.291,0.073,0.426  c0.173,0.508,0.639,0.82,1.209,0.823C41.344,26.579,41.808,26.578,42.271,26.578z M33,27.817c-3.384-0.002-6.135,2.721-6.182,6.089  c-0.049,3.46,2.72,6.201,6.04,6.272c3.454,0.074,6.248-2.686,6.321-6.043C39.254,30.675,36.462,27.815,33,27.817z M21.046,31.116  v0.082c0,4.515-0.001,9.03,0,13.545c0,0.649,0.562,1.208,1.212,1.208c7.16,0.001,14.319,0.001,21.479,0  c0.656,0,1.215-0.557,1.215-1.212c0.001-4.509,0-9.02,0-13.528v-0.094h-2.912c0.411,1.314,0.537,2.651,0.376,4.014  c-0.161,1.363-0.601,2.631-1.316,3.803s-1.644,2.145-2.779,2.918c-2.944,2.006-6.821,2.182-9.946,0.428  c-1.579-0.885-2.819-2.12-3.685-3.713c-1.289-2.373-1.495-4.865-0.739-7.451C22.983,31.116,22.021,31.116,21.046,31.116z   M45.205,49.255c0.159-0.026,0.318-0.049,0.475-0.083c1.246-0.265,2.264-1.304,2.508-2.557c0.025-0.137,0.045-0.273,0.067-0.409  V21.794c-0.021-0.133-0.04-0.268-0.065-0.401c-0.268-1.367-1.396-2.428-2.78-2.618c-0.058-0.007-0.113-0.02-0.17-0.03H20.761  c-0.147,0.027-0.296,0.047-0.441,0.08c-1.352,0.308-2.352,1.396-2.545,2.766c-0.008,0.057-0.02,0.114-0.029,0.171V46.24  c0.028,0.154,0.05,0.311,0.085,0.465c0.299,1.322,1.427,2.347,2.77,2.52c0.064,0.008,0.13,0.021,0.195,0.03H45.205z M33,64  C16.432,64,3,50.568,3,34C3,17.431,16.432,4,33,4s30,13.431,30,30C63,50.568,49.568,64,33,64z" />

</svg> 

</body>
```

The CSS:

```
#insta {
   display: block;
   float: right; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: -12px;
    -webkit-transition: fill 2s;  
     -moz-transition: fill 2s; 
    -o-transition: fill 2s;  
     transition: fill 2s; 
}
#insta:hover {
    fill: #ff0000;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kBM9U/1/